# How to Checkout out a branch

Tags: python, gitpython

I got gitpython working to clone a repo, now i need to checkout out branches inside that repo i've been looking at the documentation but cant seem to find it

```
import git
import os
import shutil

DIR_NAME = "temp"
REMOTE_URL = "<REPO>"

if os.path.isdir(DIR_NAME):
    shutil.rmtree(DIR_NAME)

os.mkdir(DIR_NAME)

repo = git.Repo.init(DIR_NAME)
origin = repo.create_remote('origin', REMOTE_URL)
origin.fetch()
origin.pull(origin.refs[0].remote_head)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
repo.git.checkout('branchename')
```

or, if the branch does not yet exist..

```
repo.git.checkout('-b', 'branchename')
```